# Flex container stretches to full width when items wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the flex container to expand as much as the largest row when the items wrap.
Given the container below, it should expand as much as the first row, leaving no gap on the sides.

[image]

```css
#main {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 16px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}

#main div {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px; text-align: center;">
  <div id="main">
    <div style="width: 145px; background-color:coral;">1</div>
    <div style="width: 40px; background-color:lightblue;">2</div>
    <div style="width: 70px; background-color:khaki;">3</div>
    <div style="width: 100px; background-color:pink;">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you cannot do this

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: min-content` to the flex div.

```css
#main {
  width: min-content;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 16px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;">
  <div id="main">
    <div style="width:145px;height:50px;background-color:coral;">1</div>
    <div style="width:40px;height:50px;background-color:lightblue;">2</div>
    <div style="width:70px;height:50px;background-color:khaki;">3</div>
    <div style="width:100px;height:50px;background-color:pink;">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: min-content introduces some extra rows in some cases. In the example below, items were originally wrapping into two rows but now they wrap into three.

https://imgur.com/8bwXAnn